# How do I know that a file backup from a Linux server was successful?

Tags: linux, backup, oracle-linux

Here is the scenario, I have been tasked with backing up production Oracle server running on Linux. According to the process left by the person from whom I took over, I connect to the server using WinSCP and copy the folder named `backup` to an external disk. I did a backup so how do I know that all the files are backed up? Windows backup tool shows that the backup is completed.

Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What protocol are you using with WinSCP? Is it SFTP? See [How to perform checksums during a SFTP file transfer for data integrity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30056566/850848)

Answer (score 2):

Restore from backup media to a test system. Spot check by opening a few files, and check number of files and size is reasonable compared to the source volumes. Restore applications, and leave the now in sync with production system to users.

> It’s a restore system not a backup system. [-- Raymond Blum, Google SRE](http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/2/3/how-google-backs-up-the-internet-along-with-exabytes-of-othe.html)

Comment: Thanks this more a manual process. Is there a tool or command to check?

Comment: Use restore procedures from the previous person. Write new documentation where this does not exist.   How manual or automatic to make this is up to you. We cannot know the processes at your organization, and you did not provide enough detail for how the technical restore works anyway.

Comment: Thanks John, there is in fact no documentation on the back process, the knowledge share happened in a verbal manner with no documentation. What do you think would be best approach the management?

Comment: Management probably won't have any more details.  If you don't have docs, and you don't know how to restore, then you probably need to make a new one.